# Vim cursor going outside of character bounds in normal mode

Tags: vim, mode, text-cursor

Some setting changed on my vim.  In normal mode, I can now click anywhere and my cursor will go there.  (This is in normal mode.)

The behavior used to be that if I clicked past the end of the line, the cursor would go to the last character of the line.

I hope I've explained this sufficiently, but is there a way to get the old behavior back?

Thanks!

Comment: No, "some setting" didn't change. *You* changed it, probably by copy-pasting from someone else's `~/.vimrc` without reading the documentation.

Comment: romainl - I figured out what it was.  I was playing around with DrChip's DrawIt plugin.  It was that plugin that changed the setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably set the option [`virtualedit`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27virtualedit%27) somewhere. To turn it off for the instance you can use `:set virtualedit=`. Or to permanently disable it remove it from your vimrc.

Answer (score 2):

The feature is call virtual edit. You can disable this with:

```
:set virtualedit=
```

See `:h 've'` for more information.

Comment: That did the trick!  Heh. It looks like you and FDinoff answered almost simultaneously.  Thanks for the answer!